# Selecting specific words from a file in Python

Tags: python

I am completly new to python, and I need a specific answer. I need to print only the authors name from a list of reference in a file by using python code.

Comment: at least show us the list of reference in a file

Comment: Hey @TrinityBlue, we do need some information before we can answer your question. First, what is the list of reference? Have you done any research yet on this problem or have you tried anything? We literally cannot do anything without this information (except the second question, which is really more about whether you have put any effort yet.)

Comment: I am new to the world of programming, just started this year, from the ground up.  Need to learn python on my own for Bioinformatics. I have tried looking into it on my own, which there is a big world out there on the subject, and was hoping to get something somewhere here.  I have tried using: my_file = open('prog_rev_ref_list.txt', 'r')
#loops over each line in the file
for line in my_file.readlines():
    authors = line
    author = authors.split()
    print author[1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a brute-horse algorithm to check if each word in the file is the last name of an author.

```
bookFile = open("someBook.txt", "r"); ### replace with the actual txt file location

fullText = bookFile.read(); ### reads the text in bookFile
words = fullText.split(' '); ## an array of all of the words in the bookFile

bookFile.close();

authorLNList = [ "Rowling", "Tolkien", "Twain", "Martin" ]; ### replace with the actual reference list of authors

for word in words: ### iterates over each word in the book
    if word in authorLNList: ### if the word is the last name of an author
        print( str( word ) );
```

This only checks for last names of authors, but you can easily check for multi-word strings as well with a bit of editing.